# What is the name of this questions asking with emotions card game?

Tags: identify-this-game

A player draws a card from 2 different stacks.

1. First stack: a question that the player must ask another..."will you marry me?".
2. Second stack: an emotion or attitude...."Aloof".

The player must ask that question in that manner.

What is the name of this game?

Comment: Can you describe the cards in detail : comic book characters, or photographs, or text only? An image would help...